# Получить количество строк по столбцу, значение которых равно NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT COUNT(cust_email) FROM customers WHERE cust_email is NULL;
```

Пример входных данных:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему пишет в результате `0`?

Я хочу получить количество строк, которые в столбце `cust_email` равны `NULL`.
Написал запрос верно, а выдает `0`, с чем связано?

Comment: `COUNT(cust_email)` не считает `null` в колонках, замените на `count(0)`.

Comment: @0xdb как ответ опубликуйте)

Comment: @Suvitruf Если дубля не найду, слишком часто встречающаяся заблуждение, чтобы ещё ответа не было.

Comment: @0xdb я вот не припомню дубля)

Comment: @Suvitruf Уговорили, по быстрому тоже ничего не нашёл.

Comment: ["Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 8):

Таково стандартное поведение функции [COUNT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-aggregate.html):

> count(*expression*)
>   number of input rows for which the value of *expression* **is not null**

Она не считает строки со значением `null` в колонках. Замените её аргумент на символ `*` или любой константный литерал, например:

```sql
create table t1 (nullable varchar(16));
insert into t1 values (null);
insert into t1 values ('val1');

select count (nullable) as cnt, count (*) as nulls 
from t1
where nullable is null
;

       CNT      NULLS
---------- ----------
         0          1
```

[рабочий пример на `db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=22c83e124cd8201e74c5ac33cde2f0dc).

Comment: По стандарту - `count(*)`. Для postgresql никаких негативных эффектов от использования стандартного синтаксиса нет.

Comment: @Мелкий В смысле? count (expression)  тоже стандарт.

Comment: но зачем подставлять какой-то ненужный, тем более строковой литерал, когда есть стандартный синтаксис подсчёта?

Comment: Хмм, я не делаю отличий между обоими вариантами, предпочитаю * не использовать вообще, но поправил ответ. "какой-то ненужный, тем более строковой литерал" - привычка,  строковый литерал всегда лучше читается, чем магические знаки - `1`, `0`, `*`, каких то негативных аспектов с применением строковых литералов пока не замечал.